# Scala, how to use functional programming to do a kind of join operation in between to complex sequences?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Suppose I have a Seq[Seq[String]] sequence, like

`val seq = for (i <- (1 to 50) toSeq) yield Seq(s"foo$i", s"bar$i")`

, which is

`List(List("foo1", "bar1"), List("foo2", "bar2"), ..., List("foo50", "bar50"))`

I also had an index tuple, say
`((5, 10), (13, 17), (25, 33), (42, 49))`

What I want to get is filter the seq, get only those whose index is between the range in the second tuple and I want to add a new id in the last position.
The result should be:

`List(List("foo5", "bar5", "0"), List("foo6", "bar6", "0")..., List("foo10", "bar10", "0"), List("foo13", "bar13", "1"), List("foo14", "bar14", "1")..., List("foo17", "bar17", "1"), List("foo25", "bar25", "2"), List("foo26", "bar26", "2")... List("foo33", "bar33", "2"), List("foo42", "bar42", "3"), List("foo43", "bar43", "3")..., List("foo48", "bar48", "3"), List("foo49", "bar49", "3"))`

I can achieve this using procedural programming, but the code smell is ugly. How can this be done in a scala style functional way?

Comment: expandRanges, zipWith, filter

Comment: Something like `indexes.zipWithIndex.map { case ((start, end), idx) => seq.slice(start, end).map(_ + idx.toString) }` it may have some typos, I am on a cellphone. Also note this could be extremely inefficient if the underlying **Seqs** are **List** but if you have **Vectors** it would have a reasonable performance; also you may use an **Iterator** or a **View** to avoid allocating the `zip WithIndex` not sure if it would be a way to do the `slice` and the `map` also in one go.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `flatMap` not `map`?

Comment: @Bergi I guess `map` OP wants a nested **Seq**  but as I said I haven't compiled the code and my in mind compiler is not the best _(specially now that I am just going to bed)_ so maybe I am missing something. My idea is that if my snippet does helped OP I would post a proper answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, join-type operations can easily be expressed using for comprehensions:

```
val ranges = Seq((5, 10), (13, 17), (25, 33), (42, 49))
for {
  i <- (1 to 50).toSeq
  ((lower, upper), j) <- ranges.zipWithIndex
  if i >= lower && i <= upper
} yield List(s"foo$i", s"bar$i", j.toString)
```

However be aware that this will require time proportional to the product of the lengths of the two lists. If these get sufficiently large, you'll need a more optimized solution.

Comment: Would you plz elaborate on how the time proportional gets increased to the product of the lengths of the two lists and how to make a more optimized solution, thanks